# Shell scripting- processing hidden files

Tags: file, bash, shell

I'm working on a project where I have to process the contents of a directory passed in as an argument, and I need to include invisible files (ones that start with .) as well. This is how I'm approaching it

```
#!/bin/bash

cd $1
for file in `dir -a -d * `;
do
#more code blah blah
```

even though I use the -a tag on the dir command, it still ignores invisible files. Any ideas why?

Comment: Hi. Three things 1) Welcome to Stack Overflow! 2) When you are pasting code in a question, please highlight the code and either hit CTRL+K or click on the button that looks like braces `{ }`.  3) Please accept the answer that best solves your question by clicking the checkbox next to the up/down counter. Upvoting it as well doesn't hurt either ;) Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just do:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s dotglob
cd "$1"
for file in *; do
  # more code blah blah
done
```

From the `bash manpage`

> When a pattern is used for filename expansion, the character ‘.’ at
>   the start of a filename or immediately following a slash must be
>   matched explicitly, unless the shell option dotglob is set.

Comment: +1 - It would also be good to explain why his attempt is bad (word-splitting)